# Is there any method to perform check-in and check-out operations of TFS code repository from Jenkins build?

Tags: visual-studio, jenkins, tfs, build, tfs-2015

My ultimate goal of this exercise is to update TFS code repository from the contents (i.e., files and folders) which are getting copied from another source.

Following is the exact scenario in my project:

- There exists a code repository in VSTS Online
- Have setup Jenkins on my local computer.
- Configured Jenkins to create a workspace for TFS code.
- Written powershell scripts in the build step to copy files from another source to the workspace folder configured for TFS.

Till this point everything is working fine. In the next step, I want to update TFS repository from whatever is there in the workspace.

Any idea of how I can achieve this?

Thanks,

Nirman

Comment: How about using the **tf** command line tool from a windows batch file? You can use it to [add](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/add-command), [checkin](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkin-command), or [checkout](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/checkout-or-edit-command) files as required.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to use [tf command](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/tfvc/use-team-foundation-version-control-commands)  with a script during the build just like Stefan suggested.

If you want to use Windows Explorer to manage TFS version control files, you can also try to use [Microsoft Visual Studio Team Foundation Server 2015 Power Tools](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/898a828a-af00-42c6-bbb2-530dc7b8f2e1). Which allow you to check-in and check-out through folders.

You need to: First, create a workspace folder, put your project in this folder.
Then use Windows Shell Extensions coming with TFSPowerTools2015 to check in/check out files in the local workspace folder.

[image]